# Attribute Error when trying to run celeryd_multi

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am getting a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrlimit'` when trying to start celeryd_multi, either manually (`python manage.py celeryd_multi...`) or as a daemon through init.d .

- I can start celeryd fine manually with `python manage.py celeryd`
- Taking `CELERYD_MULTI` out of /etc/default/celeryd causes it to crash with this error: `usr/bin/python: No module named celery.__main__; 'celery' is a package and cannot be directly executed`
- Starting celeryd_multi manually also results in the 'getrlimit' attribute error

This is what my /etc/default/celeryd file looks like:

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/code/project"

CELERYD_MULTI="python $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

CELERYCTL="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/celeryd.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/celeryd.pid"

CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings"
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
> Starting nodes...
    > w1.ip-10-28-232-109: OK
ubuntu@ip-10-28-232-109:~$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/project/manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd_detach.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    detached().execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 146, in execute_from_commandline
    **vars(options)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 37, in detach
    with detached(logfile, pidfile, uid, gid, umask, working_directory, fake):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 248, in open
    for fd in reversed(range(get_fdmax(default=2048))):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 83, in get_fdmax
    fdmax = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[1]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getrlimit'
```

Comment: a stack trace would be helpful

Comment: @jterrace: Added stack trace.

Comment: does ``import resource; resource.getrlimit`` work?

Comment: Yes: 
>>> resource.getrlimit
<built-in function getrlimit>

Comment: @Goro try to execute it from `python manage.py shell` Maybe you have your own module called 'resource'

Comment: @Igor: That was exactly the problem :)